# Golang, postgresql rows.next() panic

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I'm getting error when interating rows using rows.next() using postgresql in golang. This is only happens in several machines and in quite unpredictable timing, which make it difficult to debug.

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [recovered]
        panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 28078 [running]:
panic(0xa63ae0, 0xc420014090)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
github.com/lib/pq.(*conn).errRecover(0xc420780500, 0xc420d2ef28)
        /share/dpkg-build/pacman-build/src/github.com/lib/pq/error.go:482 +0x57e
panic(0xa63ae0, 0xc420014090)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:458 +0x243
github.com/lib/pq.binaryDecode(0xc420780728, 0xc4207806f0, 0x0, 0x30, 0xc400000017, 0xa24300, 0xc421fcb4b0)
        /share/dpkg-build/pacman-build/src/github.com/lib/pq/encode.go:76 +0x385
github.com/lib/pq.decode(0xc420780728, 0xc4207806f0, 0x0, 0x30, 0x17, 0x1, 0xa24300, 0xc421fcb4b0)
        /share/dpkg-build/pacman-build/src/github.com/lib/pq/encode.go:61 +0x6c
github.com/lib/pq.(*rows).Next(0xc42281e310, 0xc420b82000, 0x2f, 0x2f, 0x0, 0x0)
        /share/dpkg-build/pacman-build/src/github.com/lib/pq/conn.go:1369 +0x420
database/sql.(*Rows).Next(0xc42005b560, 0xc4204eb590)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1758 +0x6c
github.com/xxxxx/yyyyy/src/product/elasticsearch.getPart1(0xc4204eb590, 0xa24300, 0xc420a04190, 0x0, 0x0) <-- rows.next() here
        /share/dpkg-build/pacman-build/src/github.com/xxxxxx/yyyyyy/src/product/elasticsearch/collector.go:71 +0xff
github.com/xxxxx/yyyyy/src/product/elasticsearch.Get(0xa24300, 0xc420a04190, 0xc420a04190, 0xa24300, 0xc420a04190, 0xc420980a00)
        /share/dpkg-build/pacman-build/src/github.com/xxxxxx/yyyyyy/src/product/elasticsearch/collector.go:29 +0x118
```

From the call-stack above the panic comes from binaryDecode function which I imagine explain why it's only happening in some machines. There might be some bad network package or the message got corrupted, so the driver couldn't decode the message then failing.

However I don't know where to go after this, anyone has idea?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested this code with the race detector? That is the first thing you should do with seemingly random or unpredictable bugs.

Comment: haven't yet,
is this good starting point for me [Data Race Detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) ?
or do you have another suggestion

Comment: I am using prepared statement, if it race condition, it could be coming from there.

Comment: There's not much to the race detector, just enable it for you binary and monitor the logs. I'm not sure what you mean with the prepared statement, that doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: using race detector is not possible, its overhead is too much in production. My staging setup couldn't reproduce this issue, I need to figure out how to reproduce this issue in staging.

Answer (score 0):

The driver expects a 4 byte slice to encode as an integer, but is panicking when trying to index the individual bytes.

Could the data accidentally be nil, or a data type less than 4 bytes?

In the driver [github.com/lib/pq/encode.go](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/encode.go#L76):

```
case oid.T_int4:
    return int64(int32(binary.BigEndian.Uint32(s)))
```

In encoding/binary [Uint32](https://golang.org/src/encoding/binary/binary.go?s=7232:7296#L99) (this line panics with index out of bounds):

```
return uint32(b[3]) | uint32(b[2])<<8 | uint32(b[1])<<16 | uint32(b[0])<<24
```